# How to update multiple rows with select statement referencing same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, Salesperson, and the current name column shows the following:

```
Undefined - 0
Sam Brett-sbrett
Kelly Roberts-kroberts
Michael Paramore-mparamore
Alivia Lawler-alawler
Ryan Hooker-rhooker
Heather Alford-halford
Cassandra Blegen-cblegen
JD Holland-jholland
Vendor Accounts-VENDOR
Other Accounts-OTHER
Rose Johnson-rjohnson
```

I've developed the following query to extract the name (minus the ID on the end) with which I want to update this column:

```
SELECT left(salesperson_name, CHARINDEX('-', salesperson_name) - 1)
FROM Salesperson
------------------------
Undefined 
Sam Brett
Kelly Roberts
Michael Paramore
Alivia Lawler
Ryan Hooker
Heather Alford
Cassandra Blegen
JD Holland
Vendor Accounts
Other Accounts
Rose Johnson
```

I have attempted numerous variations of the following, but get the understandable

> Subquery returned more than 1 value...' error.

```
begin tran
update salesperson
set salesperson_name = (SELECT left(salesperson_name, CHARINDEX('-', salesperson_name) - 1)
FROM Salesperson)
```

Comment: The issue is that your subquery isn't [correlated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017#correlated) with the outer query, hence it processes the entire `Salesperson` table for each row in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not a simple

```
update salesperson
set  salesperson_name  = left(salesperson_name, CHARINDEX('-', salesperson_name) - 1)
```